# ASP.NET - Bootstrap Drop Down Navigation Working Only on Root Pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently developing an internal application using ASP.NET 4.0 using the Yeti Bootstrap Theme.

I'm having an issue with my navbar dropdown navigation. Pages that are stored in the root of the website are able to use the drop down features without any issues. The first level drop down is a mouse click, but for the drop down branching off of the Admin selection within "Interface Jobs" appears when the cursor hovers over the selection.

The problem that I'm having is that when I navigate to a page within a drop down, and then try to use the drop down navigation when on that page, the drop downs won't work. I can only navigate to the Log Viewer page.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue might be? Thanks in advance for any help!

Master Page Code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BootStrapMasterPage.master.cs" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>ILG Interfaces</title>`
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ILG Interfaces | <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" FormatString="Logged in as {0}" runat="server" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Interface Files <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink10" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceFiles/Statistics.aspx" runat="server">Statistics </asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceFiles/OutstandingSignups.aspx" runat="server">Outstanding Signups </asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/LogViewer.aspx" runat="server">Log Viewer </asp:HyperLink></li>




            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Interface Jobs <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceAdmin/GIValidation.aspx" runat="server">Generic Interface Validation </asp:HyperLink></li>
                            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceAdmin/GIValidation.aspx" runat="server">Generic Interface Validation Rules </asp:HyperLink></li>
                            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceAdmin/GIValidation.aspx" runat="server">Generic Interface Postcode Validation </asp:HyperLink></li>
                            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceAdmin/GIValidation.aspx" runat="server">Synoptik File Sequences </asp:HyperLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceJobs/Jobs.aspx" runat="server">Jobs </asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceJobs/JobSteps.aspx" runat="server">Jobs Steps </asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" NavigateUrl="~/InterfaceJobs/JobQ.aspx" runat="server">Jobs </asp:HyperLink></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Clients.aspx" runat="server">Maintain Clients </asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>


     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery that I think might be the issue:
      $().dropdown('toggle')

```
  $(document).click(function () {
      $(".dropdown").hide('slow');
  });

  $(".dropdown").click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your call to the jquery is before your call to bootstrap